# Can we perform action after user clicks cancel / continue on browser tab close confirmation in Angular11?

Tags: angular, browser, angular11

I am working on a Angular 11 project where I have implemented browser close confirmation dialogue using following code

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onWindowClose(event: any): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = true;
    return;
  }
```

With this I saw confirmation dialogue whenever user tries to close or redirect using URL

[image]

Now I have a scenario where I want to perform different actions based on user's click on `Leave` or `Cancel`. Is it possible to do so? If yes please advise on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you find solution, but I had same problem today and this works:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  onUnload(event: Event) {
    //some backend API call...
  }
```

so basically BeforeUnload will ask you whether you want to close or not, and then Unload will actually do something if you want to close it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you open the dialog?

If you are using window.confirm, there should be a return boolean value to indicate which button you have clicked.

```
if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: the above code itself opens the dialog, it listens to WindowClose event and open the dialog.

Comment: How do you open the confirmation dialog?

Comment: in above code `event.returnValue = true;
    return;` these two lines tells browser to confirm before closing/redirecting there is no need to open any popup manually.